# Jquery problem getting text from a script tag?

Tags: jquery

I have this small HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("script").each(function()
                {
                    if($(this).attr("type") == "code")
                    {
                        alert($(this).text());
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

<script type="code">
var Text = "Text";
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When run using Firefox the alert displays the text contents of the `<script type="code">` tag. When run in IE8 it displays nothing.

Do you know why? I'm stumped.

Comment: script type `code` doesn't exist per any specs i know of. i wouldn't be surprised if IE simply blocked out all unknown scripts as a security measure. what are you trying to achieve? you might want to consider using some other markup, such as the `code` element.

Comment: change to *<script type="text/javascript" </script>*

Comment: He obviously wants to use the script tag to store some information and is therefore using a non standard attribute value. changing it would not help his problem. You can see a similar example here: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: Yeah Darko is right, i'm writing a script to grab source code from a <script> tag and reformat it into a table. So i'm not really using the <script> to embed any executable code on the html page.

Comment: Then script isn't an appropriate tag. See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324627/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-data-in-an-html-page , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340104/best-way-to-include-unobtrusive-information-on-a-web-page for various alternative strategies.

Comment: The thing is it's source code i want to present on the page. So the script tag is appropriate. I've written a syntax highlighting engine similar to alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter and replace the script tags with nicely formatted tables using jQuery. If i use other tags to contain the source code, it is parsed as html and can alter the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have more luck with .html() and if that doesn't work try `this.innerHtml`. I did not test this however.

I do have another tip for your code however. If you want only scripts of type code you can have a single selector instead of having to check the attribute in the loop:

```
$("script[type=code]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
    alert(this.innerHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .html() instead for better support with ie.

You can also look at: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata for storing information in script tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                    $("script").each(function()
                    {
                            if($(this).attr("type") == "code")
                            {
                                alert($(this).html());
                            }
                    });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="code">
            var Text = "Text";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```