# Can't access javascript text via css selector

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

I wan to be able to select the contents of the following script tag.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" class="sample">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var test = {};
  test.hey = 1;
  /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Running $(".sample").text() in geb results in an empty string. Is there a way to access the plain text script contents?

Comment: why do you have this tagged with Selenium?  To me, it looks like you are trying to get it via jQuery

Comment: I'm using geb (http://gebish.org) which is built ontop of selenium. geb uses a jQuery like syntax.

Comment: Why would you need to get hold of contents of a script tag? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm generating a javascript tag inside by web application. Depending on which site you're currently on, the contents of the javascript may vary. I want to test if the correct javascript is written using geb.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the framework you mentioned but it is possible that `$(".sample").text()` returns an empty string because the code within the `<script>` tag is not a visible piece of HTML. As mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897984/jquery-problem-getting-text-from-a-script-tag) try using either `$(".sample").html()`.

This of course is assuming that the gebish framework API supports a `.html()` method on the object. You could find something equivalent in the API docs if this solution does not work.