# How can I make a function defined inside another function be in the window scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a wrapper for some arbitrary code (let's call it managed code). The managed code may include some functions that are defined in the window scope and are expected by other scripts on the page (horrible, 1997, practices, I know, but such is what I have to deal with), as global functions.

The purpose of the wrapper is to delay executing the wrapped code until jQuery is loaded. It looks like this:

```
(function () {
    var once = true,
    check = setInterval(function () {
        if (window.$ && once) {
            once = false; // setInterval can stack up if the UI freezes. Ensure this only gets called once.

            executeBundle();

            clearInterval(check);

            console.log('Jquery loaded');
        }
    }, 100);
})()

// Wrapper proper
function executeBundle() {
  // oodles of code of any origin
}
```

Now that the managed code is wrapped inside the `executeBundle` function, all functions/variables declared within it will be scoped to that function. This isn't a problem for the managed code itself, but for other scripts that load separately that may rely on global functions it provides.

I'd like to know if anyone knows a strategy like `eval`, but without the security issues, that may allow me to preserve the window scope for the running of the managed code. The constraint is that I can't modify the managed code at all--just the wrapper.

Comment: Can you put jquery in the `<head>`?   Then it will already be loaded, so no need to wait for it.

Comment: I don't have control over when/where the jquery is loaded @freedomn-m

Comment: So why can't you stick the code after jQuery and it will be loaded??

Comment: Have you tried prefixing with window?  In your `executeBundle()` where you define the function, define it with `window.` - eg `function loadAbc() {` becomes `window.loadAbc = function() { `

Comment: Fair question @epascarello. Thing is that some of the code is loaded via Requirejs, including jquery. So while I can put the managed code after requirejs, I can't control when jquery comes in

Comment: I thought about that @freedomn-m, but I can't modify the managed code. It's a lot and that strategy would be very error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know if anyone knows a strategy like `eval`, but without the security issues

If you're `eval`ing code of your own that you would run by having it in a `script` tag anyway, there are no security issues. You're running code either way.

You can't do this if the code you're wrapping will appear directly within `evaluateBundle` and it has declarations (`var`s and function declarations) that were supposed to be at global scope. Handling those would *require* modifying the wrapped code.

You *can* do this if you load that code separately, though, and then do a global eval on it. For instance, put it in a script block with a non-JavaScript type so the browser doesn't execute it:

```
<script type="x-code-to-wrap"></script>
```

...and then:

```
function evaluateBundle() {
    var code = document.querySelector('script[type="x-code-to-wrap"]').textContent;
    (0, eval)(code);
}
```

(The `(0, eval)(code)` bit is the global `eval`, [more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)).

You may have to adjust the `textContent` part of that for cross-browser compatibility. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897984/jquery-problem-getting-text-from-a-script-tag) suggest using jQuery's `html` function:

```
function evaluateBundle() {
    (0, eval)($('script[type="x-code-to-wrap"]').html());
}
```

[Live example on JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/midayumubo)

Comment: Holy crap, that's clever. The managed code I'd be running is mostly libs/frameworks and in-house code, not ad-related junk. So it should be safe, but not future-proof...

Comment: @seebiscuit: The caveat I can think of is that if any of the code uses `document.write` expecting to be part of a script that's parsed during the initial HTML parsing, it won't work. But hopefully since it's not ad-related junk, you don't have that issue...

Comment: I wish I could give this answer another upvote for introducing `(0,eval)`

Comment: @seebiscuit: Ooooh, you should post that as an answer, it's *at least* as good as the eval approach and quite possibly better. But you should have had to remove the `type` attribute (or make it `"text/javascript"`), I'm surprised it works if you don't...

Comment: Yup! I realized that I had to change `type` as I was implementing. I'll add the answer, but yours is official.

Answer (score 2):

Based on T.J. Crowder's phenomenal answer, I realized that I could add the managed code to a `<script>` element and add that to the `<head>` like this:

```
var codeBundle = // Code in one long string

function evaluateBundle() {
    var script = $('<script type="text/javascript"/>')

    script.html(codeBundle);

    $('head').append(script);
}
```

And let the parser evaluate the code.